# index route for a resource is POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Game model in my Rails app. In the routes file, I created a resource route for it

```
resource :games,  defaults: {format: :json}
```

However, when I made an ajax request to url: 'games' using Backbone, I got a 404 error. Running `rake routes` shows that 'games' is a POST request, and is linked to the create action of the games controller, which is obviously not what it's supposed to be (see the rake routes for my Question resource below).

I've also included my Game model code below.

Can anyone explain what I've done wrong?

rake routes Game.rb

```
 games POST   /games(.:format)                 games#create {:format=>:json}
 new_games GET    /games/new(.:format)         games#new {:format=>:json}
 edit_games GET    /games/edit(.:format)       games#edit {:format=>:json}
 GET    /games(.:format)                       games#show {:format=>:json}
 PUT    /games(.:format)                       games#update {:format=>:json}
 DELETE /games(.:format)                       games#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

By comparison, here  are the routes for the  Question model

```
questions GET    /questions(.:format)                  questions#index
          POST   /questions(.:format)                  questions#create
new_question GET    /questions/new(.:format)           questions#new
edit_question GET    /questions/:id/edit(.:format)     questions#edit
question GET    /questions/:id(.:format)               questions#show
         PUT    /questions/:id(.:format)               questions#update
         DELETE /questions/:id(.:format)               questions#destroy
```

Game model

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :creator_id, :name

  has_many :results 
  has_many :users, :through => :results

  has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum #for Active_record_reputation gem


  class << self    
    def win?(chars_left, incorrect_guesses)
      chars_left == 0 and incorrect_guesses < 6
    end



    def correct_response?(correctanswer, guess)
        correctanswer == guess
    end 


    def correct_guess?(char_clicked, final_word)

      puts char_clicked
      puts final_word =~ /#{char_clicked}/i
      if final_word =~ /#{char_clicked}/i 
        true
      else
        false
      end 

    end



  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `resource :games` won't give you an `index` route as it's a singular resource, you need to change it to `resources :games`, [have a look here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources).

Comment: +1, i was blindly looking at the code and wondering why there wasn't no index action :)

Comment: @Zippie  it has happen to every single Rails developer since the dawn of the framework.